# Is data grouping supported in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I tried to work with something like merging a set of data from days to months, but Highcharts doesn't group them. The chart tries to show all the data. I am not using Highstock.

Is data grouping supported in Highcharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts itself doesn't suport data grouping. You have two options:

1. Use highstock, which does have support for it: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping
2. Group the data yourself.

If you want to process your data to group it, you will need to loop through your daily data, adding each value into a new data array, indexed on month.

Comment: Is this still the case? I mean it would make sense, it is a charting framework, not a data crunching API.

Comment: Yes, it is still the case.